# Basic Play 2.0 WebSocket request header not found

Tags: scala, websocket, playframework-2.0

I am trying to do a very simple proof of concept using Play 2.0 websockets.

Here is what I am doing right now:

- Defining the WebSocket in my controller:

```
def wsrequest = WebSocket.using[String] { request =>

  // Send a single 'Hello!' message 
  val out = Enumerator("Hello!") 

 // Just consume and ignore the input
  val in = Iteratee.consume[String]()

  // tie the in and out values to each other
  (in, out)
}
```

- Add the route in my routes file

```
GET     /wsrequest                  controllers.Application.wsrequest
```

- Use the following inside the javascript in my index.scala.html:

```
var sock = new WS("@routes.Application.wsrequest().webSocketURL()")
```

However when I try and compile this I get an error:

```
[info] Compiling 5 Scala sources and 1 Java source to target\scala-2.9.1\classes...
[error] target\scala-2.9.1\src_managed\main\views\html\index.template.scala:32: Cannot find any HTTP Request Header here
[error] Error occurred in an application involving default arguments.
[error]             var sock = new WS(""""),_display_(Seq[Any](/*11.33*/routes/*11.39*/.Application.wsrequest().webSocketURL())),format.raw/*11.78*/("""")
[error]                                                                                                                     ^
[error] one error found
```

Am I missing a step ? Or I have I made a mistake in what I have done above?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your template needs an implicit request header, like this:

```
@(message: String)(implicit request: RequestHeader)
```

Comment: One more general note: Make sure you don't reassign "request" in a not intended way before implicitly using it. This caught me and resulted in the same "Cannot find any HTTP Request Header here" message.